# Magento and Dear Inventory integration

Tags: magento-1.9

Does anyone have any experience of doing this?
It is all new to me and I have tried to follow the guidelines but get the following error...

SOAP-ERROR: Parsing WSDL: Couldn't load from 'http://www.fsfixings.com/index.php/api/v2_soap/index/?wsdl=1' : failed to load external entity "http://www.fsfixings.com/index.php/api/v2_soap/index/?wsdl=1"

Any guidance would be much appreciated!

Comment: Where are you calling this from? I see one is http and the other is https

Comment: From the Magento installation?

Comment: Could you update your question with the script that calls this WSDL url?

Comment: it is done through the Dear Inventory site so not sure what it is sorry! They have said the installation is blocking the API, could it be to do with my hosting?

Comment: Ah, I'm guessing they're trying to retrieve it over `https` which you don't have for the API

Comment: do you know I can do to resolve that?

Comment: Either the Dear Inventory system calls it without `https` or you have to implement a certificate. Best way I guess would be to contact Dear Inventory. If you can't get it fixed with them I won't mind helping out by contacting them for you, in that case google my name and send me an email

Comment: Doesn't look like it is a https issue, rather the host blocking the call from itself, do I need to add an allow rule for the IP address to a htaccess file? I have tried to contact Dear but they said it is an installation issue not them. Thank you!

Comment: Well the thing is that if I click on the link or run it through a validation tool it comes back as a valid XML/Webservice.  Can you ask them what the status code is they get back? 200, 404, 503 or something like that?

Comment: @KatieFoulkes how did you resolve this?